# Setting a time picker to current time using xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently i am using a date and time picker to capture the date and time of the when the user inputs information. The date picker is working fine and is being set at the current date but i cant seem to get the time picker to set at the current time, it is constantly at 00:00. Is there a way to get this to the current time.

I have tried the following and its still doing the same:

```
TimePicker TimePicker = new TimePicker();
TimePicker.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

This is currently how the code is running in my program:

.cs file

```
DateTime FeedbackdateTime = DatePicker.Date.Add(TimePicker.Time);

initialmedfeedback.Datetimetaken = FeedbackdateTime;
```

.xaml file

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ></DatePicker>
<TimePicker x:Name="TimePicker" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ></TimePicker>
```

model .cs file

```
/// DateTime description getter/setter
/// </summary>
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "datetimetaken")]
public DateTime Datetimetaken
{
    get { return datetimetaken; }
    set { datetimetaken = value; }
}
```

Comment: DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay should work

Comment: There is no need to create a new TimePicker Objekt !
You're assignment TimePicker.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay should be fine. 

Now it is just the question, where are you doing this assignment? 
If you do it in the constructor  of your .xaml.cs file you need to do it after the call to "InitializeComponent();"

Comment: @JannikR. i have called it after the "InitializeComponent();" and now i get 12:00AM instead of 00:00

Comment: @Jason Still not fixing it, could it be an issue with the simulator or something ?

Comment: based on the code you posted it's really not clear what you're doing.  Can you post all the relevant code related to the time picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

In your code, you should remove this line

```
TimePicker TimePicker = new TimePicker();
```

Because you have already created the `timePicker` in Xaml.

In your code behind, just use this line to set `time` of `TimePicker`:

```
TimePicker.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

`TimePicker` here is the name of `TimePicker` you defined in Xaml;

```
<TimePicker x:Name="TimePicker"/>
```

You set the name `TimePicker` the same as control's name `TimePicker`, it is not recommended and confusing.

**Ways of setting time:**

1.

```
timePicker.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

2.

If you want to customize the time:

> In code, you can initialize the Time property to a value of type
>   TimeSpan:

```
TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker
{
  Time = new TimeSpan(4, 15, 26) // Time set to "04:15:26"
};
```

So, you can get current `hour`, `minute`, `second` and then set them to `TimePicker .time`:

```
string hour = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH");
string minute = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm");
string sencond = DateTime.Now.ToString("ss");

_timePicker.Time = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(hour), Convert.ToInt32(minute), Convert.ToInt32(sencond));
```

In xaml:

```
<TimePicker x:Name="_timePicker" Format="T"/>
```

Additional:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm") // for non military time
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") // for military time (24 hour clock)
```

Refer: [timepicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/timepicker)

[Offical sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/TimePicker/)

Comment: Thanks man, that did it. I just removed the TimePicker TimePicker = new TimePicker(); and it worked

Comment: @MarkPW Happy to hear that. By the way, have you solved the problem that add a swipe gesture to SFChart? I updated my answer in that thread.

Comment: No not at the minute, ive parked it for now but i will go back soon and try it again, thanks again.